# JavaScript: Reason for using callback as a function parameter

Tags: node.js, express

Can anyone simply explain why we use the keyword callback as a function parameter when we are defining a function in a model.

Comment: because it is literally a callback, when everything is done you do a callback to inform it at least; in this case, when the task is done, it will execute the callback function for the same purpose

Comment: This is probably more of a English Language question than a programming one. At least where I'm from (Canada), company's call centres sometimes give you a "callback" option, where they automatically call you back when it's your turn to be helped. It's conceptually the same idea.